# Работа с анимацией

Tags: winforms, c#

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые Все!

На первой форме играет анимация, есть вторая форма... Как сделать, чтобы анимация играла некоторое время, затем автоматически загружалась вторая форма?

**Добавление.**

Через цикл то можно, только вторая форма будет сразу запускаться =)

Это форма с анимацией...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MainMenu
{
    public partial class men : Form
    {
        public men()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Create a Bitmpap Object.
        Bitmap animatedImage = new Bitmap("SampleAnimation.gif");
        bool currentlyAnimating = false;

        //This method begins the animation.
        public void AnimateImage()
        {
            if (!currentlyAnimating)
            {
                //Begin the animation only once.
                ImageAnimator.Animate(animatedImage,
                    new EventHandler(this.OnFrameChanged));
                currentlyAnimating = true;
            }
        }

        private void OnFrameChanged(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Force a call to the Paint event handler.
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //Begin the animation.
            AnimateImage();

            //Get the next frame ready for rendering.
            ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();

            //Draw the next frame in the animation.
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.animatedImage, new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Это код кнопки, по которой запускаются все дела))

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(@"D:\Установка\MainMenu\1.wav"))
        sp.Play();

    // прогрессбар
    pBar1.Show();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pBar1.Value = i;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    men fr = new men();
    fr.TopMost = true;
    fr.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    fr.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    fr.Show();

    //скрыть текущую!
    this.Hide();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    run1 frm4 = new run1();
    frm4.TopMost = true;
    frm4.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    frm4.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    frm4.Show();
}
```

Comment: Какая платформа и среда разработки?

Answer (score 1):

Завести [таймер](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer(VS.90).aspx). По срабатыванию таймера спрятать первую и показать вторую форму.

Answer (score 0):

А как насчёт того, чтобы использовать PictureBox с Gif'ом для отображения анимации, и отображать вторую форму по таймеру?